# Haskell print or show in a function

Tags: haskell, printing

I am new to Haskell and trying few things. I have a small program.

```
module Collatz where
compute_collatz :: Integer -> Integer
compute_collatz x = if even x then evenComputation else oddcomputation
    where evenComputation = div x 2
          oddcomputation = 3 * x + 1

compute_steps :: Integer -> Integer
compute_steps 1 = 0
compute_steps num = 1 + compute_steps(compute_collatz(num))
```

I wanted to print the sequence of numbers generated by each `compute_collatz(num)` call. How can I add a `print` or `show` statement in either `compute_steps` or `compute_collatz` functions

Comment: You can work with [**`trace :: String -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace),, so something like `compute_collatz x = trace (show x) (if ...)`

Comment: So isn't it should be something like compute_steps num = trace (show num)(1 + compute_steps(compute_collatz(num))) as i wanted to print all the computed numbers+

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach.

A better alternative is to make the result of the function a *list* of visited numbers, instead of just the final one.

```
collatzSeq :: Integer -> [Integer]
collatzSeq 1 = [1]
collatzSeq x
 | even x     = x : collatzSeq (x`div`2)
 | otherwise  = x : collatzSeq (3*x + 1)
```

Then you can use this list for counting steps, printing, whatever. Note that thanks to lazyness you need need to worry that the whole list would need to be computed before the printing starts – it'll just print as you go in the computation.